# Difference between `=` and `:=` in sbt

Tags: sbt

```
val gitHeadCommitSha = taskKey[String]("Determines the current git commit SHA") 
gitHeadCommitSha := Process("git rev-parse HEAD").lines.head
```

In the above code, I suppose `=` creates a key (which I suppose is analogous to declaring a variable and `:=` declares a setting. So does SBT allow declaring a key and a setting of the same name? OR is `gitHeadCommitSha` a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gitHeadCommitSha` is a value of type `TaskKey[String]`, while `gitHeadCommitSha := Process("git rev-parse HEAD").lines.head` is a value of type `Setting[Task[String]]`.

In terms of `=` vs `:=`, `=` is the scala primitive to define a binding, while `:=` is a method on `TaskKey` (and the other keys) to define a setting (which you typically don't assign to a variable).

So what that code does is define a task key of name "gitHeadCommitSha" and then set the value of that key.